# javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: Illegal argument

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I am trying to make a query as usual but this time I need three conditions in my query. So I have written a code and the query is something like this:

```
Query query = pm.newQuery(LokationsEntry.class, " personalgroup == 1 && openningtime < now && closingtime > now");
query.declareParameters("java.util.Date now");

entries = (List<LokationsEntry>) query.execute(now);
```

Now is a date parameter.

The problem is that if I remove one of the date comparisons it works fine. But it gives me this error if I use both date comparisons. I need to query so that the time is between closing and opening times. Do you know how to solve this puzzle?

Comment: I solved this by comparing the dates in the same argument like openningtime < now < closingtime and it worked!

Comment: *"I solved this.."*  Congrats, and thanks for reporting back.  Could you enter your comment as an answer and mark it correct?  That would make the question (& answer) easier to find for others who are searching later.

Comment: Sorry I thought I solved it but it does work well. In my query (openningtime < now < closingtime) the inequality part with closingtime is being ignored. So it only compares with the openningtime so it is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of the documented limitation of google app engine unsolvable through query. You have to make the second filtering with your own code.